# Add JSON Objects to an array inside Retrofit call function

Tags: android, json, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Android Studio I need to retrieve all data from an API which is http://mindicador.cl/api here I need to obtain four objects which are "uf", "dolar", "euro" and "utm". Actually I can retrieve it already, the problem comes when I want to add it to an array because in a future I want to handle this array in order to show them on RecyclerView.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<IEconomicoObject> iEconomicoObjects;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iEconomicoObjects = new ArrayList<>();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(MiIndicadorAPI.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        MiIndicadorAPI api = retrofit.create(MiIndicadorAPI.class);

        final Call<IEconomicoAPI> iEconomicoAPICall = api.getAPI();
        iEconomicoAPICall.enqueue(new Callback<IEconomicoAPI>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<IEconomicoAPI> call, Response<IEconomicoAPI> response) {
                iEconomicoObjects.add(response.body().getUf());
                iEconomicoObjects.add(response.body().getUtm());
                iEconomicoObjects.add(response.body().getEuro());
                iEconomicoObjects.add(response.body().getDolar());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<IEconomicoAPI> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("onFailure", "" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

        // here is the problem, the list is empty and should be show the data added it previously
        if (!iEconomicoObjects.isEmpty()) {
            for (IEconomicoObject o: iEconomicoObjects) {
                Log.e("info", "nombre: " + o.getNombre());
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("info", "the list is empty");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

List will appear empty at the point where you are trying to read it. Since retrofit return result in a callback that is called in parallel to UIThread so , you should read the list , inside the callback.

Comment: but is there something like onPostExecute? I mean some method to do something after the callback is called?

Comment: That method is a callback inside an asynctask.. you are not using it. you are using retrofit's callback.